# how to define a set such that elements of set vary with time

Tags: set, cplex

I want to define a time-varying set for 6 hours. The elements of the set vary with time. At t = 1 hr the element of the set is {3,6,8,1,4}, at t = 2 the element of the set is {6,8,1,4}, at t = 3 hr the element of the set is {8,1,4}, at t = 4 hr the element of the set is {1,4}, at t = 5hr the element of the set is {4}, at t = 6 hr the element of the set is {}. Suggest how to write the code in OPL CPLEX to define a time-varying set.

Answer (score 0):

You can use array of sets:

```
range T=1..6;
{int} s[T]=[{3,6,8,1,4},{6,8,1,4}, {8,1,4},{1,4},{4},{}];

execute
{
  writeln(s);
  writeln(s[1]);
}
```

which gives

```
[{3 6 8 1 4} {6 8 1 4} {8 1 4} {1 4} {4} {}]
{3 6 8 1 4}
```

Comment: writeln(s[1]); gives {3 6 8 1 4}